# Interpreting percentile values for a 2D array

Tags: numpy, statistics, percentile

I have data points collected at 3 different times -

**Latest collection**

```
    receivedtime    newCol
0   1.536596e+12    43.000000
1   1.536596e+12    100.000000
2   1.536596e+12    180.000000
3   1.536596e+12    50.000244
4   1.536596e+12    3792.999756
5   1.536596e+12    897.000000
6   1.536596e+12    11343.000000
7   1.536596e+12    374.000000
8   1.536596e+12    690.000000
9   1.536596e+12    1.000000
```

**Old collection**

```
    receivedtime    newCol
0   1.536597e+12    1080.0
1   1.536597e+12    1.0
```

**Oldest collection**

```
    receivedtime    newCol
0   1.536596e+12    43.000000
1   1.536596e+12    100.000000
2   1.536596e+12    180.000000
3   1.536596e+12    50.000244
4   1.536596e+12    3792.999756
5   1.536596e+12    897.000000
6   1.536596e+12    11343.000000
7   1.536596e+12    374.000000
8   1.536596e+12    690.000000
9   1.536596e+12    492206.000000
10  1.536596e+12    420.000000
11  1.536596e+12    37.000244
12  1.536596e+12    509.999756
13  1.536596e+12    497.000000
14  1.536596e+12    436.000000
15  1.536596e+12    130.000000
16  1.536596e+12    1.000000
```

The `receivedTime` column is a `timestamp` and is always unique. `newCol` is the time difference between 2 adjacent observations.

The result of `np.percentile` on these data points is -

**Latest collection**

```
np.percentile(latest, [25, 50, 75])
array([3.25500000e+02, 7.68298069e+11, 1.53659614e+12])
```

**Old collection**

```
np.percentile(old, [25, 50, 75])
array([8.10250000e+02, 7.68298490e+11, 1.53659698e+12])
```

**Oldest collection**

```
np.percentile(oldest, [25, 50, 75])
array([4.24000000e+02, 7.68298062e+11, 1.53659613e+12])
```

Why is there a much larger fluctuation in the first quartile when compared to the second and the third quartiles? Second and third seem to be close to the same value but the first is not.

Comment: I think stats.stackexchange.com is a more suitable forum for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify `axis` parameter of [`np.percentile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html). In this case it computes the percentiles of the **flattened** array, meaning both columns taken together. This, of course, makes little sense as the numbers in "newCol" have a different meaning. Since "newCol" numbers are all smaller than "receivedTime" numbers, here's what happens:

- 25th percentile is the median of "newCol". This varies a lot between the data sets.
- 50th percentile is halfway between the largest "newCol" entry and the smallest "receivedTime" entry. Since "newCol" is tiny compared to "receivedTime", this is essentially 1/2 of smallest "receivedTime".
- 75th percentile is the median of "receivedTime", and all "receivedTime" are about the same.

Practical conclusion: either extract the column whose percentiles you want:

```
np.percentile(old[:, 0], [25, 50, 75])
```

or specify `axis=0` to get the percentiles in each column.

```
np.percentile(old, [25, 50, 75], axis=0)
```